MySQL Command Line Client on a local machine always asking for root user password and does give me a chance to log in as another user, on windows
I've installed MySQL (Community) and when run MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, first thing it always asks me for a password for the root user, it does not give me a chance to log in as another user
When I run the command
mysql> exit

It simply shuts down the Command Line Client
Anyway I can fix this?
enter image description here
When i installed MySQL i used the Full Setup Type, not sure if this info is hepfull
I was able to use MySQL Shell to log in as another user other than the root user, so that the roundabout way of doing
AI recommeded editing my.ini file
[client]
username=your_username
password=your_passsword

I thought it would change the default user from root to another user
Did not work

How are you opening the client? Usually you pass the username with the -u switch and empty -p switch to prompt for p/w, eg:
mysql -u your_username -p

You can create a batch file (something.bat) that would contain
mysql -u youruser -p

which will use the user you wanted.

See the docs here for connection options:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/connection-options.html#option_general_host
If you are connecting to the instance from within the server you can use:
$ mysql -u your_username -p

Leaving the -p argument empty will prompt you for your password.
Avoid passing your password directly to the -p argument on the command line as it can be recorded in the shell history which is not secure.
